# How can I join tables from different schemas into a single table?

Tags: aws-dms

I have multiple schemas (One for each client) with the same tables in Aurora - MySql.
I want to collect the data from all the tables and create a new table in RedShift that would include all the columns from the source tables adding a new "schema" column that would be part of the primary key.

Example:

**In Mysql I have:**

Schema1.user (id, name) pk (id)

Schema2.user (id, name) pk (id)

...

Schema96.user (id, name) pk (id)

**In Redshift I need:**

dw.user (schema, id, name) pk (schema + id)

Is it possible to do this with transformation rules in AWS DMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it is better done through a consolidation job in post-processing with Glue. Not sure you can do this with DMS currently, but you can explore the [DMS transformations here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html).

Answer (score 0):

We were looking to combine data from multiple clients in Aurora MySQL into one table in Redshift for data analytics, just like you are.

We solved this by setting up a DMS task with a transformation rule to rename the schema to the same name for each client:

```json
{
  "rule-id": "1",
  "rule-type": "transformation",
  "rule-name": "rename-schema",
  "rule-action": "rename",
  "rule-target": "schema",
  "object-locator": {
    "schema-name": <client-schema-name>,
  },
  "value": "combined_data"
}
```

and then setting DMS Task `Target table preparation mode` to `Do nothing` to avoid there being a race condition between the clients to clear out the table before starting the migration task.

We also added the `client` as a new column by adding a transformation rule to each table:

```json
{
  "rule-id": "2",
  "rule-type": "transformation",
  "rule-name": "add-client-column",
  "rule-action": "add-column",
  "rule-target": "column",
  "object-locator": {
      "schema-name": <client-schema-name>,
      "table-name": <table-name>,
  },
  "value": "client",
  "data-type": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 255
  },
  "expression": "'<client-schema-name>'"
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.Creating.html